# 403 error when enabling HTTPS on a web serivce

Tags: web-services, web-config

This is the first time im doing this and have come accross an issue. I think im nearly there but I need help from the gods!, (thats you guys !).

I have a web service (WCF) that works great. I now need to add an SSL certificate to this. I have installed the SSL certificate onto IIS and binded it to  the web service.

I have also added the following into my web.config

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyWebService.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="https://myDomain.co.uk/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="MyWebService.IService1">
      <identity>
        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="CertName" />
      </identity>
```

I also have the following bindings

```
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>

<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

My Issue is when I call the web service as HTTP its fine,

When I call it as HTTPS I am getting a 403 error. Im not sure what the issue is.

Help Please
Thanks in Advance

Alpesh

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

First, the end point should only be the following. I removed the other end porint

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="MyWebService.IService1" />
```

The binding should be

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="secureHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
  <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

I removed the the following line

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

This solved my issue. i hope this helps others. Thanks